# does a application context always need a war file to be loaded on the server

Tags: java, spring, jar, war

does a spring application context always needs to be inside a war file to be loaded on the server?

and if the application context is inside of a jar, which is in common/lib folder of the server .

will the spring beans inside the jar file load when the server is up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring Boot, you can build "fat jar". It contains all the dependencies and has embedded application server (jetty or tomcat). That way, when you run the jar (like ordinary java jar), application server is started with your application deployed and running inside.

For more info see [Deploying Spring Boot Applications](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications)

If you are deploying your app to a regular application server, you need WAR archive.